# AS3 - How to add bevel filter on MovieClip after I changed its color

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, filter

When I change color with

```
var blue:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
blue.color = 0xFF00B8E7;
MovieClip.transform.colorTransform = blue;
```

I add this

```
var myBevel:BevelFilter = new BevelFilter();   
myBevel.type = BitmapFilterType.INNER;   
myBevel.distance = 3;   
myBevel.highlightColor = 0xFFFFFF;   
myBevel.shadowColor = 0x000000;   
myBevel.blurX = 5;    
myBevel.blurY = 5;  
MovieClip.filters = [myBevel];
```

the result is, only color changed.

**How can I add this bevel over or on the new color that I changed?**

I looked everywhere and found no answer to my problem.
So I hope you guys here, can help me!
It seems like that the bevel takes all colors as the new color that I changed, not taking the one I specified

```
myBevel.highlightColor = 0xFFFFFF;   
myBevel.shadowColor = 0x000000;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colorTransform will apply to the entire movieclip including any children and filters. If you try a drop shadow, you will see what I mean.

METHOD #1:
You can create a parent object with the bevel filter and attach your movieclip with colorTransform.

```
    var parentObject:Sprite = new Sprite();
    addChild(parentObject);

    var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
    mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
    mc.graphics.drawCircle(100,100, 100);
    mc.graphics.endFill();

    var blue:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    blue.color = 0xFF00B8;

    var myBevel:BevelFilter = new BevelFilter();
    myBevel.type = BitmapFilterType.INNER;
    myBevel.distance = 3;
    myBevel.highlightColor = 0xFFFFFF;
    myBevel.shadowColor = 0x000000;
    myBevel.blurX = 5;
    myBevel.blurY = 5;

    parentObject.filters = [myBevel];
    parentObject.addChild(mc); 
    mc.transform.colorTransform = blue;
```

METHOD #2:
To avoid having a parent object to handle the bevel, I used two ColorMatrixFilters with an AdjustColor to accomplish what you are looking for. You will end up with 3 filters, one to make the object white, one to change to the color you want, and the last bevel filter. If you are using an IDE other than Flash, like Flex or FlashDevelop, you will need to include flash.swc into your library from 'Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc' for the fl.motion.AdjustColor package/class.

```
    var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
    mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    mc.graphics.drawCircle(100, 100, 100);
    mc.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(mc); 

    // White out the entire shape first
    var whiteAC:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
    whiteAC.brightness = 100;
    whiteAC.contrast = 100;
    whiteAC.saturation = -100;
    whiteAC.hue = 0;            
    var whiteMatrix:Array = whiteAC.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
    var whiteCMF:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(whiteMatrix);

    // Now use ColorMatrixFilter to change color
    var colorMatrix:Array = hexToMatrix(0x0000FF);
    var colorCMF:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(colorMatrix);

    // Create bevel
    var myBevel:BevelFilter = new BevelFilter();
    myBevel.type = BitmapFilterType.INNER;
    myBevel.distance = 3;
    myBevel.highlightColor = 0xFFFFFF;
    myBevel.shadowColor = 0x000000;
    myBevel.blurX = 5;
    myBevel.blurY = 5;

    mc.filters = [whiteCMF, colorCMF, myBevel];

    function hexToMatrix ( hex:uint, alpha:Number = 1 ) 
    {
        var r:Number = ((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
        var g:Number = ((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8);
        var b:Number = ((hex & 0x0000FF));

        var matrix:Array = [];
        matrix = matrix.concat([r, 0, 0, 0, 0]); // red
        matrix = matrix.concat([0, g, 0, 0, 0]); // green
        matrix = matrix.concat([0, 0, b, 0, 0]); // blue
        matrix = matrix.concat([0, 0, 0, alpha, 0]); // alpha
        return matrix;
    }
```

Comment: But I don't have parentObject. It is only one shape (custom) that I want to change color and add bevel.

Comment: I just caught an error in your code as well. the color is not a valid color. remove the last E7. 0xFF00B8 :)

Comment: You are correct but this is not the solution that I was hoping for because if I have 2 MovieClips I need to make 2 fake parentObjects and so on, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with the order in which you apply the transformations:

```
...;
myMovieClip.transform.colorTransform = blue;
...;
myMovieClip.filters = [myBevel];
```

VS:

```
...;
myMovieClip.filters = [myBevel];
...;
myMovieClip.transform.colorTransform = blue;
```

The bevel might also be supplying its own fill over whatever you're doing with the color transform. You might want to experiment with the bevel's `shadowAlpha` and `highlightAlpha` properties. Set them to 0.1 and see if your movie clip is blue-shaded.

Comment: it has no effect. I done what you said but nothing changed. It still takes the blue instead of black, other idea?